# Retrieve SQLite table into Spinner - C# Android

Tags: c#, android, arrays, sqlite, adapter

I am trying to Retrieve Data from `SQLite` and put it into a Spinner.

But the Spinner does not have anything inside it...

My code:
DBHelper.cs:

```
public List<string> GetSportCategories()
{ 
    List<string> categoryList = new List<string>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.ReadableDatabase;
    ICursor cursor = db.Query("sportCategories", new string[] { "categoryName" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.MoveToNext())
    {
        int index = cursor.GetColumnIndex("categoryName");
        categoryList.Add(cursor.GetString(index));
    }
    return categoryList;
}
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
 public void LoadSportCategories()
        {
            DBHelper dbVals = new DBHelper(this);
            List<string> sportCategoryList = dbVals.GetSportCategories();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, sportCategoryList);
            spnSports.Adapter = adapter;
        }
```

Comment: Try adding line based upon `adapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);` before `spnSports.Adapter = adapter;`

Comment: @MikeT It is still empty..

Comment: try using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, instead of `SimpleDropDownItem1Line`. I assume you are 100% sure that `sportCategoryList` is populated i.e. has more than 0 elements. (vaguely remember not being able to use dropdown layouts, been ages since I have used spinner)

Comment: It is working, but it has 49 records in there, and my SQLite table only has 7 records...

Comment: remove line `adapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);`

Comment: @MikeT I did, same result

Comment: @MikeT It seems it is looping through the table continously, aso I have a `FOREIGN KEY` in the table, could that be why?

Comment: Add breakpoint at `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, sportCategoryList);` and check # in **sportCategoryList**. My guess is that you are adding rows inadvertently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160392/discussion-between-miket-and-defalt).